# Getting the relative path of a file inside laravel's root directory

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm trying to get the relative path of an owl-carousel file inside my root directory.  I'm going to use it for my link and script tag of my app homepage.

I did try to use Laravel's helper method url() just to set it in the root directory but still, I keep on receiving a status 404 not found.

This is the sample code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('/')}}/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />

<script src="{{url('/')}}/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/owl.carousel.min.js">
```

Is there any way for this to work.

Comment: in what folder is the `OwlCarousel2-2.3.4` folder located? Is it in `public`?

Comment: Could you please also attach the folder structure with OwlCarousel2-2.3.4 ?

Comment: Nope, It's inside the root folder

Comment: You need to move it into the `public` folder

Comment: @atymic the whole OwlCarousel folder?

Comment: @atymic now it's working thank you

Comment: See  my updated answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your assets inside the `public` folder, not in the project root.

Files inside there can't be accessed.

You could also link to the CDN to avoid needing to serve the JS yourself:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha256-UhQQ4fxEeABh4JrcmAJ1+16id/1dnlOEVCFOxDef9Lw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha256-pTxD+DSzIwmwhOqTFN+DB+nHjO4iAsbgfyFq5K5bcE0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This what I'm looking for the last 2 hours. Thanks bro!